# Java code generation with XPAND (nested packages)

Tags: java, code-generation, xpand

I'm working on generating code from an existing model with XPAND. This model contains nested packages as one knows them from Java for example.

As far as I understand there are no loops or anything, so that I could concatenate for example the package declaration string.

I would like to do something like this:

```
model:
package kitchen
--package electronics
--package food
----class tomatoe
```

wanted output:

```
package kitchen.food;
class tomatoe{}
```

I should add that it should have the possibility to ask the classes for their parent classes. How to generate the import string for nested packages?

Comment: What actually is the question?

Comment: the question was how to generate the import string for nested packages

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simple way would be to define a biderectional reference between parent and child package. So in your metamodel it would be a biderectional reference of package class to itself like:

```
+---------+
|Package  |
|         |<>--+
`---------+    | 0..* containedPackages
        |      |
        +------+ 0..1 parentPackage
```

In Xpand you would do (untested, but should be enough to get the idea):

```
«DEFINE class FOR Class»
  import «EXPAND packagename FOR this.package»;
  class «this.name»{}
«ENDDEFINE»

«DEFINE packagename FOR Package»
  «FOREACH this.packageHierarchy() as p SEPARATOR '.' -»«p»«ENDFOREACH»
«ENDDEFINE»
```

Xtend - recursively find the parents, add them to the list and reverse the list order. Probably there's a more clean way which doesn't need the flatten() method:

```
List[Package] packageHierarchy(Package p):
    let list = {}:
    p.parentPackage == null ? list.add(p) : list.add(packageHierarchy(p.parentPackage)) ->
    list.flatten().reverse()
;
```

I hope the code snippets are not too broken :)

Comment: thx for the help. i agree that this is the easier way. i did not have the choice to do that, as my situation was predefined, but i´m sure this solution might be helpful to others. (i have no solution for my problem until now so i cant post it just in case somebody wonders)